# bigqueryの性能についてまとめたページを探しています

Tags: google-bigquery

※プログラミングに関する質問と少し異なります。
google-bigqueryの導入を社内で検討しているのですが、導入にあたって、ディザスタリカバリや、平均復旧時間(MTTR)、障害発生件数等、性能の詳細情報を必要としています。（社内でのシステム導入申請書を出す際に必要です）
[google公式ホームページ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla)は確認しましたが、上記に挙げたような詳細の情報を見つけることができません。。
どなたか上記に挙げた情報がまとめられたページをご存知でしたら教えて頂けないでしょうか。

Comment: Googleのサービスに関する質問はGoogleにお尋ねください。

Answer (score 1):

BigQueryのStatusのHistoryを全部集計すれば、何か分かるかもしれません
https://status.cloud.google.com/

SLAなどについては、 https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla にあります。